# To scroll pages by MS 4000 Keyboard's Zoom in Firefox without MS's drivers

Tags: macos, keyboard, zoom

I would like to change MS 4000 Keyboard's Zoom to Scrolling pages in Firefox without the use of MS's drivers which causes only problems in OS X.

**How can you change MS 4000 Keyboard's Zoom to Scrolling pages up and down in Firefox?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find anything about zooming in `about:config`, so you may be out of luck.